# Ways to iterate over undefined in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently discovered that [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not iterate of the undefined **created by holed arrays**, arrays whose individual indices were defined, but some weren't:

```
// Holed
var array = [];
array[0] = 1;
array[2] = 3;
array // => [1, undefined, 3];

// Not Holed
var array = [1, undefined, 3];
array // => [1, undefined, 3]; The "same" as Holed
```

When it comes to iteration, these two arrays, which should be identical, defined in different ways are iterated upon differently (see first sentance)

Thus are my questions,

1. Is there any way to iterate over the holed arrays?
2. I suspect that the exact bytes of these **are** actually different, and this strange behavior is due to how JavaScript displays these values which are not defined, not `undefined`. Am I correct? Is there any underlying explanation for this anomaly?

Any help is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You can iterate with a plain `for` loop. The difference is that the property `1` in the first array has simply never been set, while in the second it has.

Comment: You can turn an array with holes to an array without holes using its iterator: `const arrayWithoutHoles = [...array];` or in an ad-hoc manner `[...array].map(f)`

Comment: Filter out the vals first? `array.filter(function (f) {return f != undefined})`

Comment: @James111 try your code first?

Comment: Try this: `var holed = []; holed[0] = 0; holded[2] = 2; console.log(Object.keys(holed)); var un = [ 0, undefined, 2 ]; console.log(Object.keys(un));`

Comment: @zerkms I did, why?

Comment: @James111 because that's what OP does not want.

Comment: @James111 - OP's question 1 seems to be asking about iterating over sparse arrays in a way that includes the missing elements. How does any use of `.filter()` let you include those missing elements? (Your suggestion would let an array that explictly includes `undefined` values be treated more like a sparse array, which seems to be the opposite of what the OP is asking.)

Comment: Mayor, when you say "Iterate over the holed arrays", do you mean to include the missing elements as if they were not missing (i.e.  The behavior of a for loop), or do you mean only include indexes that are actually defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to iterate over the holed arrays?

Majority (all?) built-in `Array.prototype` functions skip holes in sparse arrays.

That means that if you want to get the `undefined` value for the missing indexes - you need to turn that array into a non-sparse array first.

With the help of ES2015 you may use array iterators. The shortest way of doing it would be to use array spread syntax:

```
[...array]
```

Then you may apply a mapping operator to it `[...array].map(handler)`

> I suspect that the exact bytes of these are actually different, and this strange behavior is due to how JavaScript displays these values which are not defined, not undefined. Am I correct? Is there any underlying explanation for this anomaly?

You are correct, it does not hold the `undefined` values explicitly. As arrays in JS are actually so called "intrinsic objects" (or shorter - just objects), their indexes are simply the properties of those objects. So when you skip an index - that property is simply not set and does not exist.

It is the same as if you access a non existing object property:

```
var o = {};
o.foo // undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled upon this, and none of these answers seemed appropriate.  When I used
`for( x of array)` I would get the appropriate number of loops, but no way to change the element (undefined and no index).

Going back to google, the next answer [ref](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-get-index-in-for-of-loop/) provided this as a solution:

```
for(const [key, value] of array.entries()) {
   console.log(key+" : "+value)
}
```

Using `entries` on the array allows us to get key/value pairs, even of undefined elements

Answer (score 1):

1.As below:

```js
// Holed
var array = [];
array[0] = 1;
array[2] = 3;
array // => [1, undefined, 3];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
  console.log(array[i])
}
```

2. `map`,`every`,`forEach`,and so on have the same performance。The callback

> It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description).

Comment: This fails, since the array length will be 2, so `i` will take on the values `0, 1`.  `array[1]` was never defined and this code will not do `array[2]` which was defined.

Comment: @Tibrogargan array length will be 3 surely.

Comment: @zerkms Yeah, just checked.  Interesting.  Object.keys(array) would return 2 elements.  What exactly does JavaScript think the 3rd key is?

Comment: @Tibrogargan it does not count the number of the elements - it just maintains the `.length` property value every time you modify the array and sets it as the `maxIndex + 1`

Comment: @zerkms Then I believe length is actually a misnomer.

Comment: @Tibrogargan it depends on the definition of the term. For me "holes" are just not initialised members.

Comment: @zerkms know if there's a quick (i.e. approx O(1)) way to determine if an array index is used?

Comment: @Tibrogargan `hasOwnProperty`?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question:

> I suspect that the exact bytes of these are actually different, and
>   this strange behavior is due to how JavaScript displays these values
>   which are not defined, not undefined. Am I correct? Is there any
>   underlying explanation for this anomaly?

That is not how JavaScript (i.e. ECMAScript) displays the values. I expect you get:

```
array // => [1, undefined, 3];
```

in a console in a browser like Firefox. Be very careful with what consoles display, as they tend to try to be helpful rather than strictly correct.

Where you have an array created like:

```
var array = [];
array[0]  = 1;
array[2]  = 3;
```

then the equivalent array literal is:

```
var array = [1,,3];
```

which makes it more obvious that the middle element is missing. Also, the built–in *Array.prototype.toString* method will use *join* so that it returns the same result:

```
array.toString() // [1,,3]
```

So no, what you are seeing is not a result of JavaScript *per se*, but of your particular browser or implementation's console.

Also, different consoles give different results, in Safari I get:

```
[1,,3] // [1, 2: 3] (3) = $2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to fill a holed Array with a built in method like `forEach()`. For example, imagine I want to fill holes of such an array with the string "bonjour" :

```
var input = [];
input[0] = 1;
input[2] = 3;
console.log(input); // [ 1, , 3 ]
input.map((item, index, arr) => {
    if (!arr[index +1] && index < arr.length-1) arr[index+1] = "bonjour";
});
console.log(input); // [ 1, 'bonjour', 3 ]
```