# How to transpose array of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am having an array of objects as below:

```js
finalList = [
  [{name: john}, {name: max}, {name: rob}],
  [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
  [{gender: M}, {gender: F}, {gender: M}],
]
```

I need the array to transpose like this:

```js
finalList = [ 
  {name: john, id: 1, gender: M},
  {name: john, id: 1, gender: M},
  {name: john, id: 1, gender: M}
]
```

The actual array of object is in nested array. Please help me guiding to transpose the array in TypeScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should state your requirements and expected output clearly. It's unclear why you have 3 repeated objects in `finalList`.

Comment: There is no built-in command to do it. It should be done manually.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a nice functional way. It assumes each array in `finalList` has the same length and same keys (so no error handling).

```js
const finalList = [
  [{name: "john"}, {name: "max"}, {name: "rob"}],
  [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
  [{gender: "M"}, {gender: "F"}, {gender: "M"}],
];

console.log(finalList);

// this is a trick to create an array of a specific size with unique objects inside it
// the fill is necessary to iterate over the holed array (https://stackoverflow.com/q/40297442/2178159)
// fill({}) won't work since it's a single object ref that will be shared
const results = new Array(finalList.length).fill(null).map(() => ({}));

finalList.forEach(group => {
  group.forEach((obj, i) => {
    Object.assign(results[i], obj);
  })
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am getting an error as below.
`Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
`const results = new Array(this.finalList.length).fill(null).map(() => ({}));
        this.finalList.forEach(group => {
          group.forEach((obj: any, i: string | number) => {
            Object.assign(results[i], obj);
          });
        });
        console.log(results);`

Comment: The code you posted appears to be fine, but it could be that `this.finalList` isn't being referenced properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721434/2178159